# R linear model with constraints

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I want to fit a linear model

```
y ~ a_1 * x_1 + ... + a_n * x_n
```

with parameter constraints

```
a_1,...,a_n >=0
```

and

```
a_1 + ... + a_n <= 1
```

in R.

Is there an elegant and fast way to do that and without using solve.QP of the quadprog package.
It would be wonderful if a short but detailed use case would be outlined for a proposed solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `constrOptim` with cost function least square and contraints defined such that `ui %*% a >= ci`.

Suppose `n=3`. You want constraints such as:

```
 a1         >=  0
     a2     >=  0
         a3 >=  0
-a1 -a2 -a3 >= -1
```

Thus you have to provide `constrOptim` the following parameters:

```
ui = rbind(c(1,0,0),
           c(0,1,0),
           c(0,0,1),
           c(-1,-1,-1))

ci = c(0,0,0,-1)
```

Set also explicitely `grad=NULL` in `constrOptim` if you do not use the gradient.

Hope it helps.